# Executing tags as per desired order and enabling BeforeAll and AfterAll in scala

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am using Bdd Cucumber with Scala. My Runner class code  is as follows;

```
@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
@CucumberOptions(
  monochrome = false,
  plugin = Array("pretty", "html:target/html/tests", "json:target/json/tests.json"),
  features = Array("path to features"),
  glue = Array("step definition pacckage"),
  tags= {"not (@wip or @repetitive)"})
class AutomationTestRunner {
}
```

I have three fearture files and I have assigned them tags. But when I do sbt test, cucumber executes test cases in alphabetic order of tags. But in my case I want to decide on the basis of tag which feature will first which will run third and so on. How can I do that?

2. In one of my step definition, Before starting of test cases I want to query database and drop all tables. As I am using scala, in my build.sbt I have specified cucumber dependencies as follows

"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-scala_2.12" % "6.2.1",
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-junit" % "6.2.1",

```
  // This dependency required for Cucumber Junit implementation to be recognized.
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test",
```

For cleaning up database, before execution of any test, I may need to use BeforeAll or BeforeClass, as far as I understan from official docs. But I am only getting option of Before and After. I am not getting any option of BeforeAll and AfterAll. How I can enable these in my code.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you have 2 questions, it is better to separate them into 2 questions. This way you can resolve one of them if it is answered. Regarding the first question, is that a unit test? Are you sure that accessing the database is what you want in your test?

Comment: It is the automation test using bdd cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your second question. In order to override the BeforeAll/AfterAll methods, you need to mixin the trait [BeforeAndAfterAll](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html). It is located at [scalatest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest), so make sure you have this dependency defined in your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: I mentioned scalatest in my build.sbt but didn't got these options

Comment: Are you sure it is imported? Can you see it in the external libraries?

Comment: yes I can see it in external libs but when I type before in my scala class it gives only two options Before and BeforeStep